# My fixed Header does not have margin-right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

my website has a normal header and I want the header to change in a fixed header when the user scrolls down. The layout is centered through margin: auto 0; and so is the original header. 
But the new header begins correcty in the left but continues til the width of the screen, not of the layout. 
I don´t know how to fix this and make the design still responsive.

This is the code from the container, the first header and the fixed (or new) header:

```
.page_wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1400px;
        min-width: 330px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
}

.header {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 5px;
        border-style: none none solid none;
        border-color: var(--color1);
        transition: all 0.2s ease;
} 

.menu-fixed{
         position: fixed;
         z-index: 1000;
         margin: 0 auto;
         top:0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 60px;
         /*background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);*/
         background: white;
         box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Edit: this is the html code that concerns the header:

```
<body>
<div class="page_wrapper">

<div class="header">
<a href="test.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="toggleNavigation()" class="menu_icon">&#9776;</a>
<nav class="navigation responsive" id="topNav">
        <a href="">Angebote</a>
        <a href="test.html">Produkte</a>
        <a href="">Über uns</a>
        <a href="">Kontakt</a>
</nav>
</div>

<script>
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ){
                        $('.header').addClass('menu-fixed');
                } else {
                        $('.header').removeClass('menu-fixed');
                }
        });



</script>
```

Comment: If you can share your HTML source, it would be helpful. But try to add .menu-fixed{left: 0; right: 0}. I guess you want to align your fixed header in the center horizontally.

Comment: I added that and now the header occupies the whole screen width, it is still not centered. I will add the html code

Comment: Try to add .menu-fixed{ max-width: 1400px;}.

Comment: yeah that worked!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
   .menu-fixed{ 
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      max-width: 1400px;
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why should he do that? What does it do? Teach him to fish. Don't just throw him a fish.